# Deleting data from memory when user logs out with Flask

Tags: python, flask

I have a project with flask. After the user is logged in, the csv files are uploaded and these files are kept in a folder with the same name as the user's 'id'. When the user logs in later, he can access the new file or the pre-existing file. When the user accesses a file, the file is stored in a dict() with the user 'id'. If the user wants to work on another file, the file is changed in dict(). So far everything is smooth. But if the user closes the browser without logging out, the file is still kept in the dict() and takes up memory space. What I want is to delete the csv data in the user's key in dict() if the user is not active or after a certain period of time. I've been thinking about this for a very long time, I tried socketio or some different methods, but they are not exactly what I want. Is there a different way to this? Thank you in advance for your answers.

Comment: How large is the file?  Unless it's tens of megabytes, there's no real point in keeping it in memory.  Just read it from disk at every request, and write the finished product out after.  Remember that user interactions typically occur at LONG intervals, in computer terms.

Comment: First of all, thank you very much for your quick reply. The problem is that I need to keep it in memory. Because when the user makes changes on the data, he can navigate on the data with the back and forward button. So if the user makes a change, there must be a way to undo it. I did this, but as I said, I couldn't find a solution for it to occupy memory.

Comment: You could keep a list of the user actions in a stack in a file, so you can undo them later.  Or, you can keep a timestamp with the user data, and run a period task to clean up old interactions.

Comment: I keep the user's last interaction date in the database but I couldn't find how to control it